# Validate Bitcoin address using Javascript

Tags: address

I know there is a similar question but its 7 years old and the answer doesn't work. Now, many things have changed, including the addresses themselves. So, is there a js library I can trust that can validate addresses on 2021

Answer (score 2):

Use bitcoinJS's https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/27a840aac4a12338f1e40c54f3759bbd7a559944/src/address.js#L101 toOutputScript function in a try-catch block

Comment: Looks fine but I can't load the script address.js `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`. Have you used it before?

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/ilyavf/tx-builder/blob/4185f6c9614832b67d087eb561237e4dd3883e76/src/tx-builder.js#L9-L84